# Call a program from Powershell w/ very long, variable argument list?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am currently trying to convert a series of batch files to powershell scripts.  I would like to run a compiler for the source files that exist in a directory, recursively.  The compiler requires a long list of arguments.  The catch is, I want the arguments to be variable so I can change them as needed.  This is a typical call from the batch file (simplified for readability and length):

> "C:\PICC Compilers\picc18.exe" --pass1
>   "C:\Src Files\somefile.c"
>   "-IC:\Include Files" "-IC:\Header
>   Files" -P
>   --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,+download,+stackwarn,-config,+clib,-plib
>   --opt=default,+asm,-speed,+space,9 --warn=0 --debugger=realice -Blarge --double=24 --cp=16 -g --asmlist "--errformat=Error   [%n] %f; %l.%c
>   %s" "--msgformat=Advisory[%n] %s" --OBJDIR="C:\Built Files"
>   "--warnformat=Warning [%n] %f; %l.%c %s"

This command executes fine when included in a batch file, but I start getting errors when I copy and paste the command into powershell.  This is only my second day working with powershell, but I have developed with .NET in the past.  I have managed to scrape together the following attempt:

```
$srcFiles = Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Include "*.c"
    $srcFiles | % {
    $argList = "--pass1 " + $_.FullName;
    $argList += "-IC:\Include Files -IC:\Header Files -P --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,+download,+stackwarn,-config,+clib,-plib --opt=default,+asm,-speed,+space,9 --warn=0 --debugger=realice -Blarge --double=24 --cp=16 -g --asmlist '--errformat=Error   [%n] %f; %l.%c %s' '--msgformat=Advisory[%n] %s' '--warnformat=Warning [%n] %f; %l.%c %s"
    $argList += "--OBJDIR=" + $_.DirectoryName;
    &"C:\PICC Compilers\picc18.exe" $argList }
```

I know that I probably have multiple issues with the above code, namely how to pass arguments and how I am dealing with the quotes in the argument list.  Incorrect as it is, it should illustrate what I am trying to achieve.  Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling command line applications from PowerShell might be really tricky. Several weeks ago @Jaykul wrote great blog post [The problem with calling legacy/native apps from PowerShell](http://huddledmasses.org/the-problem-with-calling-legacy-or-native-apps-from-powershell/) where he describes gotchas which people will meet in this situations. And there is of course solution too ;)

**edit - correct url**

The article is no more available, so it's only possible to see that through web.archive.org - see [cached article](http://web.archive.org/web/20110527182556/http://huddledmasses.org/the-problem-with-calling-legacy-or-native-apps-from-powershell/)

Comment: I was actually having this problem, powershell was using commas to delineate arguments where the compiler program was using spaces.  Great link.

Comment: Unfortunately the blog post is gone, making this answer useless

Answer (score 4):

Make `$arglist` an array instead of a string. A single string will always be passed as a single argument which is what you *don't* want here.

Comment: Imho that's not enough - in original version `-IC:\Header Files` is in double quotes, whereas in Posh version it is not. This is one of problems that cause errors.

Comment: Joey is right, need to make this an array.  It also wouldn't hurt to stop using spaces in your folder names.  :)

Comment: @Jason: Folder names can contain spaces and whenever a tool cannot cope with that I consider it broken ;-)