# Output ssh command to text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to output the following command to a text file in powershell, but I cannot seem to get it working:

```
ssh -v git@git.assembla.com  | Out-File C:\output.txt
```

Comment: Is your command generating any output?

Comment: Yes, we need some more information to help you with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [post below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505983/call-a-program-from-powershell-w-very-long-variable-argument-list) with using native apps, you could try using Start-Process, e.g.

`Start-Process ssh "-v git@git.assembla.com" -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput stdOut.log -RedirectStandardError stdErr.log; gc *.log; rm *.log`

Answer (score 1):

Working on the same problem I made a detail post on my blog [How to SSH from Powershell Using Putty\Plink](http://www.christowles.com/2011/06/how-to-ssh-from-powershell-using.html) but the short version is this bit of code. But sure you try it after installing putty.

```
   Function Invoke-SSHCommands {

       Param($Hostname,$Username,$Password, $CommandArray, $PlinkAndPath, $ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey = $true)

       $Target = $Username + '@' + $Hostname
       $plinkoptions = "-ssh $Target -pw $Password"

       #Build ssh Commands
       $remoteCommand = ""
       $CommandArray | % {$remoteCommand += [string]::Format('{0}; ', $_) }

       #plist prompts to accept client host key. This section will login and accept the host key then logout.
       if($ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey)
       {
            $PlinkCommand  = [string]::Format('echo y | & "{0}" {1} exit', $PlinkAndPath, $plinkoptions ) 
            #Write-Host $PlinkCommand
            $msg = Invoke-Expression $PlinkCommand
       }

       #format plist command
       $PlinkCommand = [string]::Format('& "{0}" {1} "{2}"', $PlinkAndPath, $plinkoptions , $remoteCommand)


       #ready to run the following command
       #Write-Host $PlinkCommand
       $msg = Invoke-Expression $PlinkCommand
       $msg
    }

    $PlinkAndPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"
    $Username = "remoteshell"
    $Password = "pa$$w0rd"
    $Hostname = "Linuxhost"

    $Commands = @()
    $Commands += "ls"
    $Commands += "whoami"

    Invoke-SSHCommands -User $Username -Hostname $Hostname -Password $Password -PlinkAndPath $PlinkAndPath -CommandArray $Commands
```